# sorting by month & adding the column value

Tags: c#

I am doing a c# project and I have the following scenario:

I am working with visual studio and I have a winform which contains two combobox as shown in the screenshot.

The first is of months, the second is of years and a button by the side. I also have a table which contains two columns named date d(atatype small datetime) and price (varchar).

When the button is clicked I want that according to the month and year it checks the table and display the total sum of the column of price in a label.

Is that possible to do? I am not using any datagrid or anything dataview such type. I am using a label to display can I calculate and show the sum?

Comment: Please read [faq] and [ask] a few times..

Comment: There is no screen shot.

Comment: sorry for the problem i updated my question

Comment: you said "I have a table", what table Database Table, DataTable or what?. In your application into what you read this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an [ADO.NET Entity Data Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb399247%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) then you could use this approach. Just tie the GetValues() method to either your button click event or a combo-box selection changed event.

```
//Get the data from your combo boxes. 
public void GetValues()
{
    string month = monthComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString(); 
    string year = yearComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString(); 
    InsertValuesInDatabase(month, year); 
}


//Insert the values into your table
public void InsertValuesInDatabase(string month, string year)
{

    try
    {
        using (var db = new MyEntities())
        {
            var newDateValueRecord = new DateValue() 
                            {
                               Month = month, 
                               Year = year
                            }

            db.DateValues.Add(newDateValueRecord); 
            db.SaveChanges(); 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e); 
    }

}
```

Comment: sir how it will know which table in the sql database the column is? I mean you dont have written and connectionstring then how it will work? And i dont want to insert the data i want to retrieve the data and add (sum) and the sum will be in the label.text. Can it be done?

Comment: @shariq_khan - Can you list the columns in your table?

Comment: @shariq_khan - If you're using Visual Studio, you can go to Project / Add New Item / ADO.NET Entity Data Model to create a data model of your table or database.  What happens is that ADO.NET creates objects that mirror your tables.  You can then create an object that has the same name as your table (e.x. var person = new Person()).  This approach does not require typing SQL commands.  You simply add the new object to the table as shown in the InsertValuesInDatabase method above.

Comment: sir can you tell me with the help me connection string as i am better in that. i am also trying yours but can you help me through that method like connection string and sqlqrery and sql command sql datareader. i dont know what such techniques named.

Comment: sir i am not adding the value tot the database i want the sum of the all the column values. sorting with month. and want to retrieve it to the label